# Размер карточки RecyclerView 3/4 экрана

Tags: android, xml, recyclerview

Есть `RecyclerView` в котором есть вертикальный список карточек.  И вот вопрос, можно ли как-то засетить их размер на 3/4 (75%) высоты экрана?

Если задать им размер в `dp` то экран будет не адаптивный, на одном телефоне он займет весь экран, а на другом половину. Знаю что можно написать свой LayoutManager, но это задача не из тривиальных, а хочется как бы нормального решения и при этом чтоб не писать полотно кода.

Если у кого-то есть идеи как это можно реализовать буду рад.

**UPD:**

Условно, у нас все карточки должны занимать вот такой размер экрана. И внизу следующая карточка должна выглядывать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Получите высоту экрана программно. Программно же указывайте её для вьюхи, которую вы возвращаете из onCreateViewHolder

Comment: Ну в целом это мысль. Спасибо

Comment: а если у карточки указать не match_parent а wrap_content или это тоже идея не очень?)

Comment: Тогда они будут по размеру карточек. Т.е. одна больше, другая меньше

Comment: я вас понял, тогда мой ответ вам ничем не поможет

Comment: вот нашел такой вариант - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51201482/android-percent-screen-width-in-recyclerview-item, может пригодится :)

Comment: Ну да это в целом как раз решение, и наверное самое правильное. Как я и писал через LayoutManager. Просто думал, может что-то не знаю и есть более простые решения. Но за ответ тож спасиб

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В целом решение через переопределение `LayoutManager` оказалось достаточно простым. Нужно всего-лишь переопределить метод `checkLayoutParams()` и в нем задать размер нашего `ViewHolder-a`.

```
recyclerView.layoutManager = object : LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false) {

                override fun checkLayoutParams(params: RecyclerView.LayoutParams?): Boolean {
                    val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
                    val windowManager =  requireContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
                    windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)

                    val height = displayMetrics.heightPixels

                    params?.width = width * 0.75
                    return true
                }
            }
```

Спасибо @Andrew за ссылку.